# How to merge dataframes in Pandas while maintaining multi-index when one dataframe is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge some dataframes with the following line of code:

```
df_list = [...]

required_columns = ['timestamp']
default_empty_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(columns=required_columns)

default_empty_dataframe['timestamp'] = pandas.to_datetime(default_empty_dataframe['timestamp'], unit='ms')
default_empty_dataframe.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True, verify_integrity=True)

merged_df = \
    functools.reduce(
        lambda left, right: pandas.merge(left, right, on=['timestamp'], how='outer'),
        df_list,
        default_empty_dataframe
    )
```

The value `default_empty_dataframe` is required to handle cases where the iterable `df_list` is empty. Without this `functools.reduce` doesn't know how to calculate a value.

The dataframes typically look like this and have a 2-level multiindex.

```
                      AACT
                      open   high    low  close
timestamp
2023-06-12 18:17:00  10.10  10.10  10.10  10.10
2023-06-12 18:22:00  10.10  10.10  10.10  10.10
2023-06-12 18:39:00  10.10  10.10  10.10  10.10
2023-06-12 19:25:00  10.15  10.15  10.15  10.15
2023-06-12 19:40:00  10.15  10.15  10.15  10.15
...                    ...    ...    ...    ...
2023-12-29 20:55:00  10.42  10.42  10.42  10.42
2023-12-29 20:56:00  10.42  10.42  10.42  10.42
2023-12-29 20:57:00  10.42  10.42  10.42  10.42
2023-12-29 20:58:00  10.43  10.43  10.43  10.43
2023-12-29 20:59:00  10.44  10.44  10.44  10.44

[1005 rows x 8 columns]}
```

This is what the `default_empty_dataframe` looks like.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

The merge code produces this warning:

```
FutureWarning: merging between different levels is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. (1 levels on the left, 2 on the right)
```

I understand why this warning is produced. In principle it doesn't make much logical sense to merge a dataframe with a 2-level multi-index with something which (I assume) has a 1-level multi index. (The empty dataframe contains no columns, but presumably by default a column index has 1 level.)

This is the result of merging. The index is flattened.

```
                     (AACT, open)  (AACT, high)  (AACT, low)  (AACT, close)
timestamp
2023-06-12 18:17:00         10.10         10.10        10.10          10.10
2023-06-12 18:22:00         10.10         10.10        10.10          10.10
2023-06-12 18:39:00         10.10         10.10        10.10          10.10
2023-06-12 19:25:00         10.15         10.15        10.15          10.15
2023-06-12 19:40:00         10.15         10.15        10.15          10.15
...                           ...           ...          ...            ...
2023-12-29 20:55:00         10.42         10.42        10.42          10.42
2023-12-29 20:56:00         10.42         10.42        10.42          10.42
2023-12-29 20:57:00         10.42         10.42        10.42          10.42
2023-12-29 20:58:00         10.43         10.43        10.43          10.43
2023-12-29 20:59:00         10.44         10.44        10.44          10.44
```

It should be possible to make this merge operation work, but I don't understand how to do it and I don't have any ideas about how I might proceed.

I would have expected it to work since there are no columns in the empty dataframe. (But it doens't.)

What **does** work is to create an empty dataframe with the same column names/multi-index structure, using a pseudo column name like `DELETE_ME` in place of `AACT`. But then after merging, the returned dataframe contains a set of 4 columns which are entirely populated with NANs, and so an extra step is required to then delete these columns.

That is obviously not a very efficient or elegant solution...

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I had a thought and wondered if I can just fake a multi-index with an empty list as the argument to the `from_product` function.

It turns out you can, and this fixes the issue:

```
default_empty_dataframe.columns = \
    pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([[], default_empty_dataframe.columns])
```